# What is $T^nf(t)$? (Question on integrals)

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

I am supposed to prove the following:

> For the operator $T$ defined by $$Tf(t)=\int_0^t(t-s)f(s)\,ds,\quad f\in C[0,1]$$
>   Show that $$T^nf(t)=\int_0^t\frac{(t-s)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}f(s)\, ds$$

I figured it would be a good Idea to first see what $T^2f(t)$ looks like. I found this:$$T^2f(t)=\int_0^t(t-s)\int_0^s(s-r)f(r)\,dr\,ds$$Now I am stuck, because I really don't know what to think of this.

N.B. Also, my plan is to use induction. Is this a good idea or a waste of time?

Comment: Change the order of integration.

Comment: Induction is a good plan, but so is your idea of trying it with $T^2$ first.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of integration.  $s$ takes all the values between $r$ and $t$, so 
$$T^2f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{r}^{t}(t-s)(s-r)f(r)dsdr$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The function $u(t)=(Tf)(t)$ is the unique solution of
$$
                u''=f\\u(0)=u'(0)=0.
$$
So $u=T^{n}f$ will be the unique solution of
$$
                        u^{(2n)}=f\\
                 u^{(0)}(0)=u^{(1)}(0)=\cdots=u^{(2n-1)}(0)=0.
$$
You should be able to verify the stated form is the unique solution.